# Two keyboards two language layouts

Tags: keyboard, language-support

I want to connect two keyboard sets to my computer. Is it possible to set each for a specific language. So that there's no need to change language each time.

For example:

- keyboard 1 types russian
- keyboard 2 types english

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `xinput` and `setxkbmap` utilities, you can set from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) so that each keyboard to have a different layout.

First, using `xinput -list | grep key` command, you have to find the device ID of each keyboard. Here s an example (my case):

```bsh
$ xinput -list | grep key
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 2.4GHz 2way RF Receiver                   id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam                                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                            id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                            id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And second, using `setxkbmap -device <key_ID> -layout <layout_name>`, set the layout which you wish for each keyboard. An example (for my keyboards):

```bsh
setxkbmap -device 3 -layout ro    #My master keyboard is set to Romanian layout
setxkbmap -device 10 -layout us   #The keyboard with id=10 is set to English (US) layout
setxkbmap -device 16 -layout ru   #The keyboard with id=16 is set to EFor Russian layout
```

Comment: Great. Works. Thanks. Maybe a separate question. But is there any way to monitor them in Plasma Desktop with some icon showing layout for each keyboard?!

Comment: @MinimusHeximus It's a separate question, and I think that a simple answer in a comment to your question is hard to be done. So, please use the [ask question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: thanks. I may ask, but to be informative: now the normal language icon is completely irresposive in Plasma. btw, a solution in unity is welcome (which I have not tested yet).

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Well, this solution should work in any [Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/65083/147044). And I tested on Unity.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which inspired me to ask a related question: *How to permanently assign a different keyboard layout to a USB keyboard?* It seems I'll need a startup script for this. First *xinput -list | grep "USB Keyboard"* will give me to device IDs (different at each startup). I need another command to cut the first ID number and then use it here: *setxkbmap -device <NUMBER> -layout <LAYOUT>*

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea how to do this in the `/etc/default/keyboard` configuration file (or other config file)?  This will probably do it: https://askubuntu.com/a/337431/42720

Comment: What's the point in setting device #3? Wouldn't #10 and #16 be enough? To which keyboards are #3 applied?

Answer (score 7):

Slightly off-topic, but if you additionally use the `-variant` option, you can type dvorak on one keyboard and workman or qwerty or any other layout on the other keyboard.

```
setxkbmap -verbose -device 17 -layout us -variant dvorak
```

Pair programming on steroids!