# USB keyboard uses wrong layout on login screen

Tags: usb, keyboard-layout

I use a keyboard layout other than QWERTY. When I turn on my laptop, the built-in keyboard uses the correct layout but the USB keyboard always uses QWERTY. As soon as I log in, the USB keyboard switches to my layout. Does anyone know why this might happen and how to correct it?

My `/etc/default/keyboard` file consists of:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="dvorak"
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Note: this issue happens on Ubuntu, Xubuntu, and IIRC, Kubuntu so it might not actually be Ubuntu-related.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the contents of the `/etc/default/keyboard` file.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I don't have access to that computer now but I will gladly do that tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, that looks unambiguous. The answers at http://askubuntu.com/questions/337411/how-to-permanently-assign-a-different-keyboard-layout-to-a-usb-keyboard might be helpful to you.