# How to Set Different Layouts for 2 Keyboards

Tags: usb, keyboard, keyboard-layout, logitech

According to [this page](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_diff_layouts_for_2_keyboards.html) I can have two different physical keyboards attached and have a different layout on each of them. I need German on one, and Danish on the other, so this would be a very elegant solution.

However, my `xinput` command output does not show me two keyboards; the wireless Logitech K230 keyboard is listed *as a pointer* because it uses the Logitech "Unifying Receiver" that also receives my wireless mouse. Also, the USB keyboard is shown as id 11 *and* 12?

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K230                             id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M705                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UVC Camera (046d:0991)                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SINO WEALTH USB Keyboard                  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SINO WEALTH USB Keyboard                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have discovered that I can use `setxkbmap` on `device 3` to affect both keyboards at once.
`setxkbmap -device 11 at` also affects device 8 (the Logitech keyboard).
`setxkbmap -device 8 dk` works - but  **only until I type anything at all on the USB keyboard!** From then on, both keyboards have the `at` layout.

- How do I assign different layouts to these two keyboards?
- Why does using one keyboard affect the other keyboard?

[This unanswered question from 2017](https://askubuntu.com/q/465488/5786) says that *"Apparently, the [Logitech keyboard] has no layout of [its] own... it just uses the layout of the last keyboard that has been used."* Since nobody has answered there, perhaps that is really an unsolvable problem? Perhaps specific to Logitech?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my laptop keyboard and bluetooth keyboard, and what ended up working for me to use `xkbcomp` with the `-i` flag to identify the id of each keyboard.  However, that seems to be essentially what you've done, only with the `xkbcomp` command rather than the `setxkbmap` command.  You could try `setxkbmap at -print | xkbcomp -i 11 $DISPLAY` and `setxkbmap dk -print | setxkbmap dk -print | xkbcomp -i 8 $DISPLAY`, but I'm not sure if it'd be any different. For me, both keyboard show up under the "Virtual core keyboard" section, so that might have something to do with it.